# Grouping THREE.Sprite to share the same transform point

Tags: three.js

I have a number of THREE.Sprite object that form part of a label: icon + info + text.

These align well when in a top down OrthographicCamera camera alignment, however when I change the camera position and rotation each sprite (groups are nested in an Object3D) transforms separately and looses it's alignment ( i.e. label is on&above icon ) .

Is there a way to share a transform point between a group of sprites?

Image to illustrate the issue when changing camera position: [image: http://imgur.com/HlPrLty]

Answer (score 0):

There is. My earlier [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757325/three-js-change-the-pivot-point-of-a-sprite/24769897#24769897) asked about essentially the same problem and offers a solution: for this to work you need to offset your sprites, take the camera angles, and rotate the sprite offset with those angles.

You can combine your sprites in a group and offset the entire group rather than each individual sprite. This'll give you the best performance, as there's less calculation to be done whenever the camera is rotated.

Assuming you're using a recent THREE.js and `OrbitControls` (for the methods being called on `controls`), with a sprite group at ( 0, 0, 0 ), matching the camera angle on your label group goes something like this:

```
var euler = new Euler( controls.getPolarAngle() + Math.PI / 2, controls.getAzimuthalAngle(), 0, 'YXZ' );
var rotationMatrix = new Matrix4().makeRotationFromEuler( euler );

var offset = new THREE.Vector3( 0, - labelOffset, 0 );
spriteGroup.position.copy( offset.applyMatrix4( rotationMatrix ) );
```

Comment: Saw it, however as I am not using a control for the scene I was not able to get it working. I am currently setting the camera position like so: `

    this.scene.camera.position.x = 100;
    this.scene.camera.position.y = 100;
    this.scene.camera.position.z = 100;
    this.scene.camera.lookAt( this.scene.scene.position );
    this.scene.camera.rotation.y = - Math.PI / 4;
    this.scene.camera.rotation.x = Math.atan( - 1 / Math.sqrt( 2 ) )
`
and was not able to get it working. Will give it another go.

Comment: As long as you compute your "polar" and "azimuthal" angles correctly based on those numbers, it will just work fine. It's easy to get the calculation wrong though.

Comment: Ended up using planes, and copying the quaternion from the camera to the parent Object3D: sceneGraphObject.setCameraQuaternion( this.camera.quaternion ); Which was much easier to maintain. Also sent a feature request to be able to group sprites : http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7941 .