# How to connect a 3-D line to the edge of a sprite

Tags: three.js

I have a 3-D scene with a Sprite that displays some text. Currently I have a 3-D Line that connects the sprite to a point on the 3-D model. The coordinates of the end of the line that touches the sprite are the same as the coordinates of the sprite itself, and the line touches the centre of the sprite. What I'd really like is to have the line touch one of the edges of the sprite. When I try it, the line touches the right point sometimes but drifts around as I rotate the scene, presumably because the scene and the sprite are not rotating in the same way.
Can anyone suggest a way of getting the effect I want?
Thank you.

Comment: As an easy workaround to get the sprite to be on top of the line, try `sprite.material.depthTest = false`. Satisfaction will depend on your use case.

Comment: Nice idea, thanks. At first it looked very good, but it does sometimes end up with the sprite being in front of the scene's object when it shouldn't be, so I'm not sure it's an improvement after all.

Comment: Then instead, try `line.renderOrder = 99; line.material.depthWrite = false;`. Sprites are rendered last, so they should render on top of the lines; setting the render order forces lines to render 2nd last.

Comment: The line ends up being rendered behind the sprite but also always behind the object(s), so much of it is often invisible when it should be visible.

Comment: Produce a _simple_ working demo, then. You can edit http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24757325) from 2014, to which WestLangley also contributed. For now I've simply doubled the height of the sprite and kept the bottom half transparent, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26393049). Later I may try the more [elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24769897) of applying an offset to the sprite.